# How can I label each equation in a row?

Tags: equations, numbering, cases

I use cases and I tend to label each equation in a row, for example in first case I  want to label each equation (1) and (2), and second case I want to label (3) and (4). How can I do this ? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
Lấy $ U,V \in \mathcal{T} $. Khi đó 
        $\begin{cases}
            U \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1 \\
            U \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2 
        \end{cases}$ và
        $ \begin{cases}
        V \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1  \\
        V \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2 
        \end{cases} $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the equation numbers manually in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\manualeqnum}{\refstepcounter{equation}\mbox{\upshape(\theequation)}}

\begin{document}

Some text $U, V \in \mathcal{T}$. Then also
$\begin{cases}
  U \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1 & \manualeqnum \\
  U \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2 & \manualeqnum \label{eq:first}
\end{cases}$ as well as
$ \begin{cases}
  V \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1 & \manualeqnum \\
  V \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2 & \manualeqnum \label{eq:second}
\end{cases}$.

See, for example, equations~\eqref{eq:first} and~\eqref{eq:second}.

\end{document}
```

You may have to play around with the spacing between the equation numbers and the rest of the text. In most cases it's actually clearer to use the `numcases` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases}

\begin{document}

Some text $U, V \in \mathcal{T}$. Then also
\begin{numcases}{}
  U \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1 \\
  U \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2 \label{eq:first}
\end{numcases}
as well as
\begin{numcases}{}
  V \cap X \in \mathcal{T}_1 \\
  V \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_2. \label{eq:second}
\end{numcases}

See, for example, equations~\eqref{eq:first} and~\eqref{eq:second}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put the "some text" in the brackets it will appear before the cases in the same line

Comment: @EladDen: The alignment would be weird with a sentence-like structure in the middle of the page. Moreover, you can not put anything after the `numcases` on the same line.

Comment: How can I call the label (1) and (3) ?

Comment: @NguyenThy: Add a `\label` for those. It would allow you to use `\eqref` elsewhere.

Comment: I done this. Thank you